# GridMvc disappear after refresh by filter or sorting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview

I am using the GridMvc from this link:

https://gridmvc.codeplex.com

I don't have problem when I have a grid in a simple new page. but when my grid is under menu(menu seems is refreshing the page) when I use sort or filter on the grid, grid disappears.

This is my controller code:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
      {
        DAL.DataManager dal = new DAL.DataManager();
        List<data> data = new List<data>();
        data = dal.get_AllDate();
        return View(data);
     }
```

and this is my view:

```
   @using GridMvc.Html
   @model IEnumerable<data>

 @{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  }

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Gridmvc.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/gridmvc.min.js")"     type="text/javascript"> </script>


   @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
  {
     columns.Add(model => model.dataUser).Titled("User").SetWidth(110);
     columns.Add(model => model.Create_Date).Titled("Create Date").SetWidth(110).Filterable(true).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
    ......

    }).WithPaging(20).Sortable().Filterable().WithMultipleFilters()
```

Comment: the grid disappear or gets no data?

Comment: @Hadee grid disappears, data is there even with the particular filter that I used when I come back to the page.

Comment: @Hadee also I am not sure why when I click on the date picker filter it is not refresh and show the filter result. nothing happen. other filters are working fine like text filters and Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too, as I noted it was performing GET and not POST, so as a workaround, I used the following at the end of the cshtml file:

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
      $(".grid-header-title").click(function (e) {
          if ($(e.target).is("a")) {
              // It was the anchor element that was clicked -- meaning, its sortable
              e.preventDefault();

              // '/Search' should be replaced with your form action
              $(document.forms[0]).attr("action", '/Search' + $(e.target).attr("href")); 
              $(document.forms[0]).submit();
          }
    });
  });
</script>
}
```